# How to unwrap a Result with different Error types with the try_trait

Tags: rust

I like to use the `try_trait` feature to write an `env` getter function

```rust
use std::env;

pub fn getU32(key: &str) -> Option<u32> {
    match env::var(key) {
        Ok(value) => match value.parse::<u32>() {
            Ok(value) => Some(value),
            _ => None
        },
        _ => None
    }
}

pub fn getI32(key: &str) -> Option<i32> {
    Some(env::var(key)?.parse::<i32>()?);
}
```

The `getU32` compiles and does work, but the `getI32` has different `Error` types from `var` and `parse`... but this shouldn't matter because the return type is an `Option`.

Comment: You could just use `.ok()` on the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
pub fn getI32(key: &str) -> Option<i32> {
    std::env::var(key).ok()?.parse::<i32>().ok()
}
```

When the `Try` trait was introduced to extend the `?` operator further, it was decided that discarding errors easily with `?` by allowing to convert `Result`s to `Option`s was not a good idea.

So if you don't care what the particular error was because you consider it not an error for the value not to be present, say that explicitly with `.ok()`.